# How to deal with insertRecord failed error when server can still be executed in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I got this error reported in docker version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB, and I checked that there are still enough server resources. I don't know why this error popped out. The error information is: `301: [EXECUTE_STATEMENT_ERROR(301)] Exception occurred: insertRecord failed. org.apache.iotdb.commons.exception.IoTDBException: ConfigNode failed to extend Region because there are not enough DataNodes`. Anyone know why this error happens?

I did not find solutions that is specific to this error message, so I need some help on my specific case on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that caused this error is because the datanode is not started, or the number of datanodes started are not enough for the cluster of Apache IoTDB. For example, the number of copies is written as 3 but only one datanode is started in IoTDB.

See if your number of datanodes started is qualified for your cluster settings.